# trying to get ocelotgui debugging working

Tags: mysql

I am preparing to write a complex stored procedure. I figure will need a debugger going so I am trying to use ocelotgui. I have installed it and can connect to my database in mysql. When I type $INSTALL which is required to set up the debugger I am getting this error:

> $INSTALL
> Need create privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need select privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need insert privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need delete privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need update privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need drop privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need create routine privilege on xxxmdbug.*. Need alter routine privilege on xxxmdbug.*.

It seems that ocelotgui creates a database called xxxmdbug but for some reason it can't on my system. I am running mySQL in Docker and I have modified the mysql.sql to have the following lines dealing with xxxmdbug.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS subs;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS xxxmdbug;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON subs.* To 'admin'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON xxxmdbug.* To 'admin'@'%';
```

It seems that I can't login with root so that I can GRANT my actual user the privileges. I though that the password for root was "", but I guess not. Anyone?

Comment: if you do not have the MySQL root password and are on a linux system try `sudo mysql -u root` By personal experience I know that it works on debian and ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you downloaded ocelotgui 1.2 from https://github.com/ocelot-inc/ocelotgui.
You might be seeing an error if database xxxmdbug already exists
(if so, drop it). But if the problem is lack of privileges
(you need `create, drop, create routine, alter routine, select, insert, update, delete, select on xxxmdbug.*`), then there's
nothing ocelotgui can do, good luck finding the root password.